Can I use API Gateway to proxy connections to my Route53 URL?
I have an API Gateway working and serving files (website) from s3 right now. I want to add another page to the website. However that page is served from ecs service (it's golang server). I got this ecs service exposed as a standalone website through route53 and it works fine. But when I add that to API Gateway it fails with error 504 "Network error communicating with endpoint". Why is this happening?
For ease of reference, lets say I have:

my s3 website running on www.web-s3.com.
my ecs service website running on www.web-ecs.com.

I want to see my ecs website when I enter www.web-s3.com/ecs-site.
What I did:
I used the same Gateway configuration just changed uri from s3 bucket to my route53 url. Terraform here:
resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "root_integration" {
  provider = aws
  depends_on = [aws_api_gateway_method.root_proxy_method]

  rest_api_id             = var.api_gateway_id
  resource_id             = aws_api_gateway_resource.main_resource.id
  http_method             = aws_api_gateway_method.root_proxy_method.http_method
  integration_http_method = "ANY"
  type                    = "HTTP_PROXY"
  uri                     = "https://${var.root_uri}/"
}

so if var.root_uri = s3 bucket, it works. But if var.root_uri = www.web-ecs.com I get 504.
